# Correct implementation of binary relevance

Tags: multilabel

I have questions regarding Binary Relevance implementation.

How to treat multi-label problem with empty class? (I have instance that cannot have any label). Should I introduce new label "NoLabel" in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, binary relevance won't help. Since the decision planes are always going to split a all negative space. and especially when you add a "No Label" Label..
So the True Negative is going to be mixed with False Negative.

But there is an expensive way to solve this by using `2^{# Labels} -1 +1` multi-class classifier. 
`2^{# Labels} -1` is for direct mapping to binary relevance, and `+1` is for the "No Label" Label.